# How to use strings from a list as variables in mediate and lm in R?

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to run lots of mediation analyses and to make it quicker I'm trying to put the lm() and mediate() functions inside a for loop. I then pass a list of lists into the loop where each item of the list is a list of three in the form c("", "", "").

Passing the items into the loop and unlisting them to have single strings for X, M and Y variables is fine. I've tried many variations on get(), eval() and assign() within the mediate() function to no avail. I think this is due to my use of get() within lm().

The way I think my code should look:

```
MedVarList <- list(c('SCI', 'rMEQ', 'SIDAS'))

for(i in MedVarList){
    X <- unlist((i)[1])
    M <- unlist((i)[2])
    Y <- unlist((i)[3])

    model.M <- lm(get(M) ~ get(X), data = NewScDat) 
    model.Y <- lm(get(Y) ~ get(X) + get(M), data = NewScDat)

    results <- mediate(model.M, model.Y, treat=get(X), mediator=get(M),
                       boot=TRUE, sims=500)
    }
```

The model.M and model.Y bits work fine. It's the treat= and mediator= inside mediate() that I simply cannot figure out. I get this error:

```
Error in get(X) : object 'SCI' not found
```

If I change the mediate() call to include the variable names directly I get a different error:

```
results <- mediate(model.M, model.Y, treat='SCI', mediator='rMEQ', 
                   boot=TRUE, sims=500)

Error in `[.data.frame`(m.data, , treat) : undefined columns selected
```

I then thought that lm() may be using "get(X)" as a variable name instead of "SCI" which is what get(X) spits out intially:

```
results <- mediate(model.M, model.Y, treat='get(X)', mediator='get(M)',
                   boot=TRUE, sims=500)

Error in get(M) : object 'rMEQ' not found
```

And just to test what's going on I looked at what get(X) and get(M) are now spitting out:

```
get(X)

Error in get(X) : object 'SCI' not found

get(M)

Error in get(M) : object 'rMEQ' not found
```

What I'm really trying to achieve is to be able to run mediate() inside a loop using a list of lists as described above. I'm doing this to avoid having multiple mediate() functions repeated with manual setup.

Comment: P.S. NewScDat contains columns for SCI, rMEQ and SIDAS.

Comment: You probably don't want to use `get` for the `lm` calls, even if they "work" as is. It will be better to construct the formulas using `paste`. Just glancing at the docs for `mediate` (I hope I have the right function, you weren't super specific about the package) it looks like `treat` and `mediator` are expecting characters, not the objects themselves, which would suggest that using `get` there will definitely fail.

Comment: Boiling this down: don't use `get`. Use `paste` to build the formulas directly in `lm` and then just pass the names of variables as characters to `treat`, etc, as directed by the docs.

Comment: mediate() is from the mediation package by Tingley, sorry.

Comment: @Bradford ... per the `r` tag (hover to see): *Use `dput()` for data and specify all non-base packages with `library()` calls.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my MWE of the successful solution:

```r
library(mediation)

MedVarList <- list(c('SCI', 'rMEQ', 'SIDAS'))

for(i in MedVarList){
    X <- unlist((i)[1])
    M <- unlist((i)[2])
    Y <- unlist((i)[3])

    FormulaM <- paste(M,X,sep = " ~ ") # Results in a string "rMEQ ~ SCI"
    FormulaY <- paste(Y,"~", X,"+",M,sep=' ') # Results in a string "SIDAS ~ SCI + rMEQ"

    model.M <- lm(FormulaM, data=df) 
    model.Y <- lm(FormulaY, data=df)

    results <- mediate(model.M, model.Y, treat=X, mediator=M,
                      boot=TRUE, sims=500)
}
```

Thanks for the tips and suggestions all. @Parfait - I've included the dput() but could you point me towards an FAQ or similar explaining the reasoning behind this?

EDIT - I understand what dput() is and does now so I've removed it from the MWE because I'd used it inappropriately.

Fuller example including useful recording of results for anyone that needs it:

```r
MedVarList <- list(c('SCI', 'rMEQ', 'SIDAS'))

NBootstraps = 5000
MediationResults <- list()

j <- 1

for(i in MedVarList){
    X <- unlist((i)[1])
    M <- unlist((i)[2])
    Y <- unlist((i)[3])

    FormulaM <- paste(M,X,sep = " ~ ")
    FormulaY <- paste(Y,"~", X,"+",M,sep=' ')

    model.M <- lm(FormulaM, data = NewScDat)
    model.Y <- lm(FormulaY, data = NewScDat)

    MediationResults[[j]] <- summary(mediate(model.M, model.Y, treat=X, mediator=M,
                                                         boot=TRUE, sims=NBootstraps))
    j <- j + 1
}
```